# Jenkins User's authorization to deploy

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, two-factor-authentication

I wanted to have 2-factor authentication in Jenkins for all the users (even super admin) and wanted to know, if it's possible and if it is, what is the possible way or do we need a plugin for it.

Plus can we have authorization for scheduling the deployment in Jenkins and if it's possible, how can we do it.

Comment: I am still not sure what your issue is... What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: Hi Slav,

Thank you for responding back!

Comment: Hi Slav!!
Related to jenkins !!
For explanation, I want to have authentication before building jobs.
You would be knowing that how we are building our jobs, I want system to prompt a password before starting building jobs and in this way, we will be able to authenticate our building process and also add some security for our jobs and builds to run.

I have found one plugin "Authorize project plugin" but not sure , if it works. I have tried installing on a test machine but it is not making any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins authorization is explained in detail here:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup

The "Authorize Project plugin" is not for what you are asking.

You will not be prompted for password everytime you start a job. Instead, you should configure individual jobs to give access to individual people. Jenkins allows that granularity.

If you really want to prompt for password at every job execution, you will have to configure job to create a new password parameter, and then as one of your first build steps, validate the entered password against... against whatever it is that you want. But that means your validation script will probably reside on Jenkins itself.

**Edit:**

- Configure Job
- Select "This build is parameterized"
- Add "String" parameter
- Call it "password"
- If on *nix environment, select "Execute Shell" for the first build step:

`set +x
if ! [[ "$password" == "mysecret" ]]; then
    echo "Bad password"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0`

- If on Windows environment, select "Execute Windows batch command" for the first build step:

`@echo off
if not "%password%" == "mysecret" (
    echo "Bad password"
    exit /b 1
)
exit /b 0`

- Add other build steps as normal.

Now, every time the job runs, it will prompt for "password", and if it doesn't match string "mysecret", the job will fail.

*Important Notes:*

- This will run after SCM checkout. If you want to run it before SCM checkout, you'd need **[Pre-SCM build step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep)** plugin.
- Anyone with "Configuration" access to the job permission or above will be able to see the "mysecret" in plain text. You can use **[EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)** plugin to configure global (or job local) password and validate against that variable, instead of "mysecret"
- Anyone with direct/remote login to the Jenkins machine will be able see the configuration file with "mysecret" in plain text (unless using EnvInject from above).
- People with enough permissions could modify or copy the job, and remove this validation.

**Once again, I implore you that the correct approach is to provide granular per-user permissions through default Jenkins security/authorization. Use "matrix" authorization to give permissions per user per job.**

Comment: Hi Slav!!

Thanks for responding.

So you are saying that I don't need any plugin for this but I need to create a script for the same and that to, on the jenkins server itself.

Comment: Can you please explain this in a bit more detail that how should I configure my job so that it will prompt a password to any user while executing jobs?

Your help is appreciated .

Regards,
Karuna

Comment: Updated, but once again, the correct approach is to provide per-user per-job permissions.

Comment: I understand Slav that you want me to follow correct approach but my client requirement is different , they want to secure the deployment process from accidental build and hence it is required to add one more step .
Accidents can happen with by admin also right! and yes I already about matrix based permissions and using that also.

Thanks a lot Slav for bearing with me and helping me in so much detail. :)